# How to format a number using format() or to_char() bulilt in functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, built-in

How do i format a number to be in the following format `31_235,3400` , I tried using `to_char()` built in function, but every time I am getting wrong output.

So the selling price of the drug should be displayed in a format with four decimals that will always be displayed and separated by a decimal point, while the integer will always be displayed and as a separator for thousands it will use an underscore, for example: `31_235,3400`

Here is my tried query

```
SELECT
    fk_id,
    prod_id,
    a_id,
    CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(TO_CHAR(price, 'FM999999999D9999999')) <= 4 THEN TO_CHAR(price, '999D0000')
    ELSE TO_CHAR(price, 'FM999999999999999_999D0000') END as price
FROM sellings
```

Here is the input table

| FK_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 156.00 |
| 1 | 213.00 |
| 1 | 359.00 |
| 1 | 620.00 |
| 1 | 110.00 |
| 1 | 97.00 |
| 1 | 1000.00 |
| 1 | 1090.40 |

The output should be as described above

| FK_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 156.0000 |
| 1 | 213.0000 |
| 1 | 359.0000 |
| 1 | 620.0000 |
| 1 | 110.0000 |
| 1 | 97.0000 |
| 1 | 1_000.0000 |
| 1 | 1_090.4000 |

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input and expected output tables?

Comment: @lemon I will, but when site will be available again, because I am solving a problem from faculty site, but seems their site have too much requests and it's unavailable now at the moment

Comment: Don't post data as images. It's considered very low quality for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set lc_numeric = 'de_DE.UTF-8';

select TO_CHAR(10000000.234, 'FM99G999G999G9999G999G999D0000');
     to_char     
-----------------
 10.000.000,2340


select replace(TO_CHAR(10000000.234, 'FM99G999G999G9999G999G999D0000'), '.', '_');
     replace     
-----------------
 10_000_000,2340
```

**UPDATE** for `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale.

```
set lc_numeric = 'fr_FR.UTF-8';

select TO_CHAR(10000000.234, 'FM99G999G999G9999G999G999D0000');
     to_char     
-----------------
 10 000 000,2340

select replace(TO_CHAR(10000000.234, 'FM99G999G999G9999G999G999D0000'), ' ', '_');
     replace     
-----------------
 10_000_000,2340
```

Comment: I am not getting underscore for thousands

Comment: What does `show lc_numeric` return in your database?

Comment: i am getting `fr_FR.UTF-8`

Comment: I don't know why, but `replace` it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Without seeing the actual data and what you are doing it is hard to offer anything more. To your question add what you have done and what the result was.

Comment: You're right, this should work, i tried it on my local database, and everything is okay, maybe they have problem with evaluating expressions at their application. I will set this as correct answer